# How to partially autocomplete?

Tags: powershell, psreadline

I'm using PSReadLine version 2.2.6 (with PowerShell 7.3.) with the following configuration options:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Windows
```

Imagine that in my history, I have previously typed:

`remove-Item -Force -Recurse .\node_modules\`

But now I just want to change `.\node_modules\`
When I start to type `remove`, PSReadLine suggest me the whole line, is there a way to validate some parts of the suggested commands?

To be more clear, I want to autocomplete until (excluded) part 2 of the following picture to be able to change the folder's name:

[image]

In this example I could just go to the end and use Ctrl + Backspace but sometimes the command parameters (like -Force and -Recurse) are located at the end and I want to keep them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the keybinding options and a sample $profile are discussed here:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much.